# Regex: Find and delete html tag which is contained in another tag

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have 2 paragraphs, with html tag **`<p class="mb-40px"></p>`** Inside this tag there is text and another <p..> tag

I need to find and delete html tag which is contained in main tag **`<p class="mb-40px"></p>`**

Example:

`<p class="mb-40px">Miracles every day <p lang="ro-RO" align="JUSTIFY">being at la home, the poet Petru Iliesu made an international appeal to condemn the killing of demonstrators, shot on the streets of town.</p>`

`<p class="mb-40px">The pleasure we feel after reading a book is different from the pleasure of tasting a dish <p class="dis23">. In the first case, pleasure is disinterested, having no particular purpose, as a release from external preoccupations.</p>`

**Output**

`<p class="mb-40px">Miracles every day being at la home, the poet Petru Iliesu made an international appeal to condemn the killing of demonstrators, shot on the streets of town.</p>`

`<p class="mb-40px">The pleasure we feel after reading a book is different from the pleasure of tasting a dish. In the first case, pleasure is disinterested, having no particular purpose, as a release from external preoccupations.</p>`

**My regex is not too good:**

**FIND:** `(?:<p class="mb-40px">|\G)\S*\K(?:\h+<\s*(\w+)[^/>]*>)(?=.*</p>)`

**Replace by:** (leave empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your modified formula which works on my side:

`<p class="mb-40px">.*\K(?:\h+<\s*(\w+)[^\/>]*>)(?=.*<\/p>)`

- you don't need to use `?:<` and `\G` if you anyway use `\K`
- `\S*` would work only if you'd have only one word without spaces between the tags, use `.*` instead
- `/` need to be escaped: `\/`

[image]

and here is an even shorter expression:

`<p class="mb-40px">.*\K<p[^>]+>`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I manage myself to find solution:

FIND: `(?-i:<p class="mb-40px">|\G(?!^))(?s:(?!</p>).)*?\K(?-i:<\s*(\w+)[^/>]*>)`

REPLACE BY: `LEAVE EMPTY`

so, if I want to find/replace something framed in two other sections, the generic regex will be:

`(?-i:REGION-START|\G(?!^))(?s:(REGION-FINAL).)*?\K(?-i:FIND REGEX)`